# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined React app

Tags: reactjs

I am fairly new to learning `react` and I am using a `react` boilerplate code from [here](https://github.com/btomashvili/react-redux-firebase-boilerplate). I am having trouble getting it started; I have `firebase` set up and need some help getting past this error. I believe that I should be using the `bind` method somewhere but I'm not too sure.

Error:

> register.jsx:19 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
>       at UserRegister.onFormSubmit (register.jsx:19)
>       at Object.ReactErrorUtils.invokeGuardedCallback (ReactErrorUtils.js:71)
>       at executeDispatch (EventPluginUtils.js:79)
>       at Object.executeDispatchesInOrder (EventPluginUtils.js:102)
>       at executeDispatchesAndRelease (EventPluginHub.js:43)
>       at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (EventPluginHub.js:54)
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at forEachAccumulated (forEachAccumulated.js:23)
>       at Object.processEventQueue (EventPluginHub.js:259)
>       at runEventQueueInBatch (ReactEventEmitterMixin.js:18)

Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { registerUser } from '../../actions/firebase_actions';

class UserRegister extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            message: '',
        };
    }

    onFormSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        const email = this.email.value;
        const password = this.password.value;
        this.registerUser({ email, password }).then((data) => {
            if (data.payload.errorCode) {
                this.setState({ message: data.payload.errorMessage })
              ;
            } else {
                browserHistory.push('/profile');
            }
        }
    );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="col-md-4">
                <form id="frmRegister" role="form" onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
                    <p>{this.state.message}</p>
                    <h2>Register</h2>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="txtRegEmail">Email address</label>
                        <input
                          type="email" className="form-control" ref="email" id="txtEmail" placeholder="Enter email"
                          name="email"
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="txtRegPass">Password</label>
                        <input
                          type="password" className="form-control" ref="password" id="txtPass" placeholder="Password"
                          name="password"
                        />
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-default">Register</button>
                    <br /> <br />

                    <a
                      href="#" className="btn btn-block btn-social btn-facebook" onClick={() => {
                          this.loginWithProvider('facebook');
                      }} data-provider="facebook"
                    >Facebook</a>
                    <a
                      href="#" className="btn btn-block btn-social btn-twitter" onClick={() => {
                          this.loginWithProvider('twitter');
                      }} data-provider="twitter"
                    >Twitter</a>
                    <a
                      href="#" className="btn btn-block btn-social btn-google" onClick={() => {
                          this.loginWithProvider('google');
                      }} data-provider="twitter"
                    >Google</a>
                    <a
                      href="#" className="btn btn-block btn-social btn-github" onClick={() => {
                          this.loginWithProvider('github');
                      }} data-provider="twitter"
                    >Github</a>

                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({
        registerUser,
    }, dispatch);
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { currentUser: state.currentUser };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(UserRegister);
```

Comment: Where you are defining `this.email`

Comment: this.email is not defined i attempted to add email and password to the state for this component and change the "ref=email" to "value={this.state.email}" but no luck @KishanMundha

Comment: `ref="email"` goes to `this.ref.email`. I suggest use `state` to textbox.

Comment: Try `<input value={this.state.email} onChange={e => this.setState({email: e.target.value}) />`

Comment: you suggest adding the email and password fields to the state and changing ref="email" to ref={this.state.email}?? i tried that and still no change any more hints? thanks @KishanMundha

Answer (score 0):

Try to use state for keep value of text input

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { registerUser } from '../../actions/firebase_actions';

class UserRegister extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            message: '',
            email: '',     // Add
            password: '',  // Add
        };
    }

    onFormSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        const email = this.state.email;         // Change
        const password = this.state.password;   // Change
        registerUser({ email, password }).then((data) => {  // change
            if (data.payload.errorCode) {
                this.setState({ message: data.payload.errorMessage })
              ;
            } else {
                browserHistory.push('/profile');
            }
        }
    );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="col-md-4">
                <form id="frmRegister" role="form" onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
                    <p>{this.state.message}</p>
                    <h2>Register</h2>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="txtRegEmail">Email address</label>
                        <input
                          type="email" className="form-control" ref="email" id="txtEmail" placeholder="Enter email"
                          name="email" value={this.state.email} onChange={e => this.setState({email: e.target.value})}    // Change
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="txtRegPass">Password</label>
                        <input
                          type="password" className="form-control" ref="password" id="txtPass" placeholder="Password"
                          name="password" value={this.state.password} onChange={e => this.setState({password: e.target.value})} // Change
                        />
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-default">Register</button>
                    <br /> <br />

                    <a
                      href="#" className="btn btn-block btn-social btn-facebook" onClick={() => {
                          this.loginWithProvider('facebook');
                      }} data-provider="facebook"
                    >Facebook</a>
                    <a
                      href="#" className="btn btn-block btn-social btn-twitter" onClick={() => {
                          this.loginWithProvider('twitter');
                      }} data-provider="twitter"
                    >Twitter</a>
                    <a
                      href="#" className="btn btn-block btn-social btn-google" onClick={() => {
                          this.loginWithProvider('google');
                      }} data-provider="twitter"
                    >Google</a>
                    <a
                      href="#" className="btn btn-block btn-social btn-github" onClick={() => {
                          this.loginWithProvider('github');
                      }} data-provider="twitter"
                    >Github</a>

                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({
        registerUser,
    }, dispatch);
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { currentUser: state.currentUser };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(UserRegister);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! @KishanMundha but seems like the error is still there after your suggested changes.

Comment: Is this related to email or password. What message we are getting.

Comment: Did you change both place from my example? In onsubmit and input jsx.

Comment: yes i added email and state variables to the state constructer and changed the <input /> to your provided example

Comment: in onSubmit ? `const email = this.state.email; const password = this.state.password;`

Comment: Thanks now the error has changed to Uncaught TypeError: this.registerUser is not a function

Comment: Remove `this` as this function we are importing from another file.

Comment: is this something wrong with firebase i believe i imported the correct libraries?

Comment: You are trying to call function by `this.registerUser` which should `register` because this function is not in you class. Just remove `this` in that line.

Comment: i tried removing that also errors still persist. Do you have slack? i can't chat on here because my rep is not high enough yet ?

Comment: registerUser is a firebase defined function i believe

Comment: Yes, I have slack. But I don't know how can I connect to you on slack.

Comment: any other way i can contact you for help? @KishanMundha

Comment: Here's my skypeid: kishanmundha

Answer (score 0):

This is bad practice. You should only inject values via: `onChange={e => this.setState({email: e.target.value})}` as mentioned already above.

I suggest you to start with a clean boilerplate (create-react-app is imo the best start) and setup first one state, for example the username/email. Log it into console before you even try to send it to firebase. This way, you always make sure that your app itself is working fine. Otherwise its always hard to tell where the issue is really coming from.

I wrote for you how you should approach this thing a small code snippet, which you can find here:

[image: Edit zn460o3xpx]

Click at the right top to open the app in a new window (symbol at the right top inside the browser of the editor) and open up your console. When you type in your email, it gets logged on submit. I suggest you to copy this and add all the values you want to log (password etc.) and first always log these into the console. If this works, add your firebase auth and try to add the push function for the database.

Greetings!